# Swift : Access variable in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, indexing, uiviewcontroller

I have a View Controller with a button, an index, and a function thats called when the button is pressed, here is an example of the code:

View Controller:

```
func buttonPressed(){

index++

}
```

Then i have a class in which i want to access and print the index from the View Controller

Class:

```
print("Index is \(ViewController().index)")
```

Obviously this doesn't work, does anyone know how I can access this? I can't really instantiate it because its a ViewController as well as it will not be the same index.I think.

Comment: you need to find better way to implement this,rather than posting question here. This is obvious that ViewController() will create new instance of ViewController class.

Comment: The class is probably created in this view controller and needs to access the property `index` of the view controller. In that case, using a delegate would easily solve this problem or if `index` doesn't change then pass it to the class whenever the button is pressed. **Either way, the given example is not enough for us to efficiently help you.**

Comment: @LeoDabus It would help so much if you could answer the question and show me how please!

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist do you need that property to persist through launches or is it temporary ? Is it a settings in your app ?

Comment: persist through launches. On the view controller screen the user will select some buttons adding 1 to the index, then when they select done, a class inheriting from UIView comes up and displays the total of the index's. So to display it I need to access the index's in the view controller from the class. Does that make sense? @LeoDabus

Comment: Why don't you save it using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Ah thats a great idea. Im new to swift, could you show me how i would do that @LeoDabus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save your index to NSUserDefaults or to a plist file. Try using a getter and a setter to make it persist automatically as follow:

**Xcode 8.3.3 • Swift 3.1.1**

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var indexA: Int {
        get {
            return integer(forKey: "indexA")
        }
        set {
            set(newValue, forKey: "indexA")
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

To load it

```
let indexA = UserDefaults.standard.indexA
```

To set/change it

```
UserDefaults.standard.indexA = 10
```

Comment: okay perfect! i think we're on to something. However, how do i set it inside the view controller and then later get it inside the class. Essentially, whats the syntax

Comment: Create a new swift file in your project and name it Extensions NSUserDefaults. Drop this extension there. After that you can change it or load it from anywhere in your code

Comment: Hey Leo, so I'm having an issue where ill do NSUserDefault().indexA = 2 and it works great, but when i rerun the application, it keeps that value. Anyway to resetting it when the app starts up?

Comment: I am updating the project it needs to be loaded inside viewWillAppear https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbifquvg54fh3qc/indexSave.zip?dl=1

Comment: Thank you so much for going to through this extent to help me, i really appreciate it. But in the project you sent me, if you increase the value to 2, then re run the application, its still on 2. Would you know how to reset it?

Comment: What you mean? just set it to zero whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Add set public or internal modifier for `index` in order to use it outside a class
2. Create an instance of `ViewController`
3. Retrieve `index` from an instance

   ```
   let vc = ViewController()
   print("index: \(vc.index)")
   ```

Comment: I did this and it crashes. Its a really weird crash as well. Thats why i came to stackoverflow

Comment: @original Please provide a whole crashing sample of ViewController. I'm not sure what you mean by `index`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = ViewController()  
print("index: \(vc.index)")
```

is not correct because vc in there is not viewController,that contain button you clicked. It has to be declared again

In case, you should have a singleton of ViewController(ex: `viewcontrollerInstall`) and put in anywhere so you can access
In `ViewDidLoad` of `ViewController`  you set  `viewcontrollerInstall = self`

And in your new class call :

```
print("Index is \(viewcontrollerInstall.index)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the reference of the view controller which has the index and button to the class where you want to access it.

From there on you can access the same index value and other properties of that view controller in that class.

Comment: Is there anything(class,struct...etc) that i can create variables(Int) in and stuff data in it and access that data from anywhere in the project?